# Why StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase throws exception in where clause

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to do a string compassion as below:

```
var nDetails = listOfServiceUrls.Where(x => String.Equals(x.Description,  
serviceName,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

But getting exception,

> System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'

If I remove the where clause it works just fine!!

```
 var nDetails = listOfServiceUrls.Where(x => String.Equals(x.Description,serviceName));
```

Comment: What is difference between two snippets?

Comment: @Alexander, My bad, second snippet does not have ignorecase, fixed now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be using Entity Framework or similar technology which actually needs to *interpret* the expression supplied as an argument to the `Where` method. It will only have translations a small subset of Base Class Library (standard .NET lib) methods and their overloads.

Hover your cursor over your `listOfServiceUrls` variable in the code editor and see what type it is. My money is on the fact that it's `IQueryable<string>` (as opposed to `IEnumerable<string>`).

EF does appear to have a translation for the instance `Equals(string, StringComparison)` method on `System.String`, so you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
var nDetails = listOfServiceUrls.Where(
    x => x.Description.Equals(serviceName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Unlike .NET you will *not* see a `NullReferenceException` if any of the strings in the collection happens to be `NULL` - because the predicate will be executed by SQL Server as opposed to the .NET runtime.

Comment: Yes, It's I changed it to IQueryable as need to load  those records with where clause and IEnumerable returns the whole thing.Is that the problem?

Comment: @Simsons, correct. And because of the interpreted nature of EF the semantics of the query that is generated from your perfectly valid .NET code may *not* be what you expect. I'll edit my answer with a solution in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

According to Linqpad, it works flawlessly ... :

```
List<string> listOfServiceUrls = new List<string>{"one","two","three"};

var nDetails = listOfServiceUrls.Where(x => String.Equals(x,  
"Two",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

nDetails.Dump();
```

Returns: `two`.

Removing the ignore case will return nothing (since obviously, `Two != two` .